# Writing an iterpreter in Ruby, not able to consume whitespace properly

Tags: ruby

So I am following the "Writing an interpreter book" and implementing it in Ruby instead of Go. I am able to scan tokens like `;` `=`, `+`, etc but it seems to behave differently when I have identifiers like `let`, `10`, etc in my input string. Tried to hunt this bug this whole week but in vain so I thought a fresh pair of eyes might be able to catch it.

Here is an overview.

- The codebase is very small and most of the logic resides in `lib/lexer/lexer.rb`
- The class `Lexer` maintains the following state a cursor for the current character in the input string, a cursor for the next character and the current character in the input string
- `Lexer` has the following methods

  - `read_char` which sets the data members to appropriate values
  - `read_indentifier` which is used to extract all the characters belonging to strings that are not reserved keywords but identifiers and call `read_char` before returning
  - `read_number` same as `read_identifier` but for numbers
  - `consume_whitespace` to skip over spaces, newlines, etc
  - `next_token` used to match the current character with the appropriate case and return its `Token` object defined in `lib/token/token.rb` and call `read_char` to increment the cursors before returning

```
require_relative '../token/token'

def is_letter(ch) #basically decides syntax acceptable for variable names
  #puts ch.class
  'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' || 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z' || ch == '_'
end

def is_digit(ch) #checks if digit
  '0' <= ch && ch <= '9'
end

class Lexer

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input
    @position = 0
    @readPosition = 0
    @ch =''
    read_char
  end

  def read_char
    #puts caller[0]
    @ch = @readPosition >= @input.length ? '' : @input[@readPosition]
    @position = @readPosition
    @readPosition += 1
    #puts "INSIDE READ_CHAR  #{@position} #{@readPosition} #{@ch}"
  end



  # SUPPOSED TO BE A LOOP WAS JUST A CONDITION. NOW FIXED.
  def consume_whitespace
    while @ch == ' ' || @ch =='\t' || @ch == '\n' || @ch == '\r' do
      read_char
    end
  end

  def read_identifier
    pos = @position
    #puts "RI: char #{@ch}  pos #{pos} position #{@position}"
    while is_letter(@ch) do
      #puts @ch
      read_char
    end
    puts "METHOD read_identifier: char #{@ch}  pos #{pos} position #{@position}\n"
    @input[pos..@position-1]

  end

  def read_number
    pos = @position
    #puts "RN: char #{@ch}  pos #{pos} position #{@position}"
    while is_digit(@ch) do
      read_char
    end
    puts "METHOD read_number: char #{@ch}  pos #{pos} position #{@position}\n"
    @input[pos..@position-1]

  end


  def next_token
    #puts @ch, @ch.class
    #puts "\nX=X=X=X=X=X=X=X=X=:  #{@ch}, #{@ch.ord},  X=X=X=X=X=X=X=X=X=\n"
    tok = nil
    consume_whitespace

    tok =
      case @ch
      when '=' then Token.new(ASSIGN, @ch)
      when '+' then Token.new(PLUS, @ch)
      when '-' then Token.new(MINUS, @ch)
      when '/' then Token.new(DIVIDE, @ch)
      when '*' then Token.new(MULTIPLY, @ch)
      when '%' then Token.new(MODULO, @ch)
      #when '==' then Token.new(EQUAL_TO, @ch)
      when '>' then Token.new(GREATER_THAN, @ch)
      when '<' then Token.new(LESS_THAN, @ch)
      #when '!=' then Token.new(UNEQUAL_TO, @ch)
      #when '&&' then Token.new(AND, @ch)
      #when '||' then Token.new(OR, @ch)
      when '!' then Token.new(NOT, @ch)
      when ',' then Token.new(COMMA, @ch)
      when ';' then Token.new(SEMICOLON, @ch)
      when '?' then Token.new(QUESTION, @ch)
      when '(' then Token.new(LPAREN, @ch)
      when ')' then Token.new(RPAREN, @ch)
      when '[' then Token.new(LSQUARE, @ch)
      when ']' then Token.new(RSQUARE, @ch)
      when '{' then Token.new(LCURLY, @ch)
      when '}' then Token.new(RCURLY, @ch)
      else
        #puts 'hello from next_token', @ch.ord
        # STATE WAS BEING MUTATED NOW FIXED
        puts "letter #{@ch}"
        puts "letter ascii   #{@ch.ord}"
        #puts "isletter  "
        if is_letter(@ch)
          literal = read_identifier
          Token.new(look_up_ident(literal), literal)
        elsif is_digit(@ch)
          Token.new(INT, read_number)
        else
          Token.new(ILLEGAL, "ILLEGAL")
        end
      end
    read_char
    return tok
  end

end
```

Now the rake test failures weren't helpful in debugging so I decided to do it simply by writing a `main.rb` script which would import and run my lexer and a sprinkled a lot of `puts`s throughout the codebase

This is my `main.rb`

```
    require_relative 'lib/lexer/lexer'

    lex = Lexer.new('five = 5;
                               ten = 10;')

    i = 1
    while i <= 8
        tok = lex.next_token
        puts "\nIN_MAIN: #{tok.type}  ==> #{tok.literal}\n\n"
        i=i+1
    end
```

This is the output of `ruby main.rb`

```
     letter f
     letter ascii   102
    METHOD read_identifier: char    pos 0 position 4

    IN_MAIN: IDENTIFIER  ==> five


    IN_MAIN: =  ==> =

    letter 5
    letter ascii   53
    METHOD read_number: char ;  pos 7 position 8

    IN_MAIN: INT  ==> 5

    letter 
    letter ascii   10

    IN_MAIN: ILLEGAL  ==> ILLEGAL

    letter t
    letter ascii   116
    METHOD read_identifier: char    pos 27 position 30

    IN_MAIN: IDENTIFIER  ==> ten


    IN_MAIN: =  ==> =

    letter 1
    letter ascii   49
    METHOD read_number: char ;  pos 33 position 35

    IN_MAIN: INT  ==> 10

       letter 
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from main.rb:8:in `<main>'
        1: from /home/palash25/gundoochy/lib/lexer/lexer.rb:89:in `next_token'
            /home/palash25/gundoochy/lib/lexer/lexer.rb:89:in `ord': empty string  (ArgumentError)
```

We can ignore the last line because I am not able to handle how to return an object for `EOF` right now but here is the gist of what is happening before that

The lexer is able to scan the tokens correctly till `five = 5` after that it skips over the next immediate character which was `;` and does return a token object for that and instead returns a token object of `ILLEGAL` type for the `\n` that is right after `;` (I even printed out the ascii values of the character to know for sure it was the `\n` returning and ILLEGAL)

This should not have happened since consume_whitespace is supposed to skip over all kinds of whitespace but it still didn't for newlines anyway after that we are able to scan the next line that is `ten = 10` but the last semicolon is nowhere to be seen in the output just like the first one

If I use an input string without any identifier or number it works perfectly fine.

Here is the link to the full codebase https://gitlab.com/palash25/gundoochy

Comment: As written in my answer, please edit your question and include the full code of your `lib/lexer/lexer.rb` file which you are referring to in your question. Only with this knowledge, it is possible to answer your question. With just the link to your repo, your question will be not helpful for future readers in about a week.

Comment: @HolgerJust  updated the post thanks for your answer, it is skipping whitespace properly now but it still skips over semicolons instead of returning a token for it

Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Lexer code (which you should include in your original question), you have the following method:

```
def consume_whitespace
  while @ch == ' ' || @ch =='\t' || @ch == '\n' || @ch == '\r' do
    read_char
  end
end
```

Here, you attempt to specify various whitespace characters. However, since you have named them with single quotes, the escape sequences with the backslash are not applied. Instead, you consume a literal backslash followed by an `t`, `n`, or `r` character.

If you use double quotes here, the characters in your source code are interpreted as tab, newline, or carriage return characters respectively:

```
def consume_whitespace
  while @ch == ' ' || @ch == "\t" || @ch == "\n" || @ch == "\r" do
    read_char
  end
end
```

Comment: I would define a constant containing the characters `WHITESPACE_CARACTERS = [" ", "\t", "\n", "\r"].freeze` and then use `WHITESPACE_CARACTERS.include?(@ch)`.

Comment: ...or `while @ch.match? /\s/`, which is equivalent to `while @ch.match? /[ \t\r\n\f\v]/`. This assumes `@ch` is known to be a single character; else while `@ch.match? /\A\s\z/`. Note `\v` is “vertical tab” and `\f` is “form feed”. The inclusion of the latter whitespace character is important for applications that involve [teletype machines](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPPF0WWCmoCeK1fZVnjAIWDbKFsXaRuE9yzntjosLOdUB0yVdc&s).